# nav-list does not collapse after selection/click (mobile/tab view)

Tags: jquery, html, css, nav

when the nav-bar is clicked and the options are selected, it moves to particular part in the same page, but the nav-list (drop-down) does not collapsed or close.
may be the function calling to the none block is not getting executed,
it would be appreciated if someone would guide for about the fuction call and also to make event call for the same.
(its required for the mobile/tab view)

Following code is html, css and js.

Since, m new to this, particular part is blocking it or wat dnt knw,!

following code html:

```
<nav class="nav">
                <ul class="nav-list" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#aboutWrapper">About</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#services">Products</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
        </nav>
```

css:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 768px) {
.nav-mobile {
    display:block;
}
.nav {
    width:100%;
    padding:0px 0 0;
}
.nav-list {
    display:none;
}
.nav-item {
    width:100%;
    float:none;
}
.nav-item a {
    background:#34495E;
    padding:10px;
}
.nav-item:first-child a {
    border-radius:5px 0 0;
}
.nav-item:last-child a {
    border-radius:0 0 5px 5px;
}
.nav-active {
    display:block;
}
.nav-mobile-open {
    border-radius:5px 5px 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px 5px 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius:5px 5px 0 0;
}
}
```

js code:

```
<script>
    (function () {

        // Create mobile element
        var mobile = document.createElement('div');
        mobile.className = 'nav-mobile';
        document.querySelector('.nav').appendChild(mobile);

        // hasClass
        function hasClass(elem, className) {
            return new RegExp(' ' + className + ' ').test(' ' + elem.className + ' ');
        }

        // toggleClass
        function toggleClass(elem, className) {
            var newClass = ' ' + elem.className.replace(/[\t\r\n]/g, ' ') + ' ';
            if (hasClass(elem, className)) {
            alert("if func");
                while (newClass.indexOf(' ' + className + ' ') >= 0) {
                    newClass = newClass.replace(' ' + className + ' ', ' ');
                }
                elem.className = newClass.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
            } else {
                elem.className += ' ' + className;
            }

        }

        // Mobile nav function
        var mobileNav = document.querySelector('.nav-mobile');
        var toggle = document.querySelector('.nav-list');
        mobileNav.onclick = function () {
            alert("func ");
            toggleClass(this, 'nav-mobile-open');
            toggleClass(toggle, 'nav-active');              
        };
    })();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please add this belwo mobileNav.onclick

```
toggle.onclick = function () {
        toggleClass(toggle, 'nav-active');              
    };
```

this would allow different call.